# AspNetUsers as foreign key in another table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

Now I am building a mini blog. when user create a post I want to insert user id from AspNetUsers in post table as a foreign key 
here the post model, so can anyone tell me the steps to make it.

```
public class Post
{
  [Required]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Content { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Path { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

  public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please can you tel us if you use CodeFirst or BaseFirst ? It's will help.

Comment: You don't need to.  You already have `ApplicationUser` in the `Post` table. For example; if you want to see all Posts by a particular user, you simply call `context.Posts.Where(p => p.User.Id == 5)`

Comment: @Cedric code first ,

Comment: @AdamVincent i agree with you , but i want insert UserId as foreign key in Post table ?

Comment: Then instead of `public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }` change it to `public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }` .. I say instead because if you have both, then it would be redundant.  Then you will need to do some additional Fluent API code to map the foreign key to the User table.  If you keep it as is, EF does all the work for you without any additional overhead.

Comment: ok after i make it , am i need write code in method create in controller for UserId ? or it will be automatically ! @AdamVincent

Comment: Correct sir, you'll need the controller to manually add the `User.UserId` to the `Posts` table.

Comment: thanks sir , please can you write the code in controller to add it manually ? @AdamVincent

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the below code to use `AspNetUsersId` as a foreign key. You can use `[Required]` if you don't want to make `AspNetUsersId` as nullable.

```
public AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AspNetUsersId")]
[Required]
public int AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
```

Yes, you have to manually set the `AspNetUsersId` when you are inserting the record in `Post` table.

Lets say you have object of class `Post` as `obj`. So you have to write the below code in your method, if `AspNetUsers` table PK is `Id`.

```
obj.AspNetUsersId = AspNetUsers.Id;
```